# Enable all components of a distribution in a repository

Tags: apt, repository

I like to live life on the dangerous side (or at least when it comes to computers). I'm trying to get the `devel` distribution working for apt. Is there a better way to enable all components of the distribution other than manually typing all of them by hand?

For example, typing

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ devel all
```

instead of

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ devel main universe multiverse restricted
```

Comment: Alright, thank you for your feedback! I've edited my question.

Comment: There is no special keyword like 'all' that would match this.  This is unfortunately the way that apt handles the URLs.  Each 'component' is listed individually in the endpoint package repository - `main`, `restricted`, `universe`, `multiverse` all correspond to certain components in the release package.  The only way to do this kind of thing would to ake a new system that behaves *without* component identification, which for Ubuntu is not something likely to happen because it'd require rewriting how apt and dpkg work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)